# How do I change the background color of a list item on hover?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a dropdown navigation menu item change background color when it is hovered over.

Here is my CSS:

```
#nav {
    background: #32CAFF;
}

#navi > li {
    display: inline-table;  
    background: #32CAFF;
    margin: 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.40s;
}

#opt li {
    float: bottom;
    transition: all 0.40s;
}

ul ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    transition: all 0.35s;

}

ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.40s;
}

ul, li, ul, li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul li ul li {
    position: relative;
    right: 16px;
}

#navi li:hover {
    background: #40BE3D;
    opacity: 1;
}

#opt li:hover {
    background: #E3B25A;
    margin: 0px;
}

#next {
    position: absolute;
    right: 900px;
}

#next ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="wraper">
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul id="navi">
            <li href="#">Home</li>
            <li href="#">Video</li>
            <li href="#">Tutorials 》
                <ul id="opt" >
                    <li>Tutorial 1</li>
                    <li>Tutorial 2</li>
                    <li>Tutorial 3</li>
                    <li>Tutorial 4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li href="#">About us</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="next">
    <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
#nav {
    background: #32CAFF;
}
```

with

```
#wraper{
    background:#32CAFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
}
#navi{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: yes background color now fixed 
but position absolute not working that way i am using position relative
now every thing is working fine

Answer (score -1):

There are several syntax errors in your CSS.

I've cleaned it up a bit, but I recommend as a first step that you run it through the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

It seems like you should [read up on how CSS selectors work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors), see other comments on this question for a few pointers.